# Why multi node config server fetch the configuration from the same node each time

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

There are three nodes running in the configuration center, when the server starts, i found that
the server fetch configuration from the same config-server each time, and only the config-server
processes the request.

My server start log:

```
Multiple Config Server Urls found listed.
Fetching config from server at: http://***:20001/
Located environment: name=onip-boot, profiles=[prod], label=null, version=..., state=null
```

I read the source code of ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java, at line 205, I found it always seems to ask the first to get the configuration and then return, unless it fails and loops the next one. So, Spring Cloud Config does not have the ability of load balancing?

```
for (int i = 0; i < noOfUrls; i++) {
    Credentials credentials = properties.getCredentials(i);
    String uri = credentials.getUri();
    String username = credentials.getUsername();
    String password = credentials.getPassword();

    logger.info("Fetching config from server at : " + uri);

    try {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        addAuthorizationToken(properties, headers, username, password);
        if (StringUtils.hasText(token)) {
            headers.add(TOKEN_HEADER, token);
        }
        if (StringUtils.hasText(state) && properties.isSendState()) {
            headers.add(STATE_HEADER, state);
        }

        final HttpEntity<Void> entity = new HttpEntity<>((Void) null, headers);
        response = restTemplate.exchange(uri + path, HttpMethod.GET, entity,
                Environment.class, args);
    }
    catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
        if (e.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
    catch (ResourceAccessException e) {
        logger.info("Connect Timeout Exception on Url - " + uri
                + ". Will be trying the next url if available");
        if (i == noOfUrls - 1)
            throw e;
        else
            continue;
    }

    if (response == null || response.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.OK) {
        return null;
    }

    Environment result = response.getBody();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: If by Load Balancing you mean Round Robin, no, it doesn't do that. However, it does Load Balance the requests using the First Alive Algorithm.

Comment: I got it. 3q. It really doesn't have to use a round load balancing strategy